# Rails. Getting PORT and HOST in Config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, rack

By default rails uses `localhost:3000` in development mode. This one is not written in any projects config files. I am currently trying to edit `./config/environments/development.rb` file to use CORS.

There is `host_and_port` method which may be used in contollers to get the HTTP requests HOST value as defined in its heading (point me if I am wrong).

I can write my `host:port` in config files manually and change it as long as my development host and port changes... But I want to configure my development environment as rarely as possible, so I need to access host and port configurations in config files.

So... how do I access my HOST and PORT in config files?

Comment: you want to access your host in the config file?

Comment: @Sunny exactly!